# copying of data from one table to another with one extra cloumn

Tags: oracle11g

how to copy table data from one table to another with one extra column which will store the date and time ,whenever the delete operation is performed in oracle11g
eg, i have one table named as student which consist of Roll_no,Name,Address,email ,each attribute is of varchar2 type and there there is another table named as audit with the same structure as of student table. I just want to copy all the records of student table in audit table along with the date whenever the row is deleted from student table

Comment: are you searching for a solution like a trigger, what is inserting into some log table when a delete stmt is executed on student?

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_delete.php